# Does sending emails to example.com cause blacklisting or other problems with email delivery services?

Tags: email, sendgrid, mailer

Apologies if this is a basic question.

After testing in development, I'm now tinkering with an application's mailer in production and want to test fire some real emails to be absolutely sure everything's working.

Will sending a few dozen real emails to a domain like `example.com` cause any issues?

I know email delivery services tend to be very sensitive to misbehaviour of any kind, so I prefer to be certain I'm not doing anything that could cause problems.

Comment: What testing are you doing? Does it do you any good if you cannot look at the sent / received messages? Just because of that I'd send to a real email address that I control.

Comment: @Robert first time doing this, but you have a really good point. I have some fictional data (10 users) in the database, and I have my actual email address as one of them, but `xyz@example.com` and similar for the rest. My plan is to simply run the app in production and test functionality manually, just to see it working with my own eyes. I think by having my own (1) email account it should be enough, but I don't want those others to get me in trouble as I've heard it's very difficult to get back on the algorithms' good side. I hope this makes sense

Comment: What difference do you expect to see between emails to yourself and the ones to example.com? Do you want to test bounce handling? A few dozens doesn't give you a good load test, and even if it did, you'd be testing sendgrid's capabilities, not your own code or markup. That said, I don't think you'll get burned for a few emails, especially not if it's a one-time thing. If you do consistently have a (high) number of bounces, it looks like you bought your recipient list from fishy sources and may be spamming. I'd ask sendgrid for their opinion.

Comment: @Robert I don't have any email lists, just my own email and (fictional) 9 example.com emails. You're right, I want to test everything out in production and make sure they send as expected, but it's actually part of broader tests to make sure the application completely works, and hence a few emails would go out as part of that. I will message sendgrid as you recommend and ask their thoughts and report back.